# flexslider won't work if adding custom properties

Tags: javascript, flexslider

As the title mentions, my problem is that [FlexSlider 2](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) won't work on my site, as I add custom properties in the following function.

This works:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();            
});
```

This won't:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide"
    });
});
```

No matter what parameter I put in, the slider won't show on the website.
I really don't understand what might be the problem. Please help me.

EDIT: It gives me these errors in dev console as i check sources

```
Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist. jquery.min.js:18
f.extend.clean jquery.min.js:18
f.buildFragment jquery.min.js:17
f.fn.extend.domManip jquery.min.js:17
f.fn.extend.append jquery.min.js:17
$.flexslider.slider.setup jquery.flexslider.js:847
$.flexslider.methods.init jquery.flexslider.js:87
$.flexslider jquery.flexslider.js:1023
(anonymous function) jquery.flexslider.js:1111
e.extend.each jquery.min.js:16
e.fn.e.each jquery.min.js:16
$.fn.flexslider jquery.flexslider.js:1102
(anonymous function) (index):40
f.event.handle jquery.min.js:17
f.event.add.i.handle.k
```

The whole code in the head of my page is

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/cm/css/slider/flexslider.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">         </script>
    <script src="/cm/js/slider/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide"
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your developer console?

Comment: Can you provide your HTML code or a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: voilà 

http://jsfiddle.net/HKCyF/

don't know if legit, but i can link you directly to the dev website.